# Undefined method error when using 'yield' and 'even?'

Tags: ruby

When I try to call a method with `select` and `num.even?` as follows,

```
def selection(array)
  puts "This is inside the method"
  return yield(array)
end

collection = [1,2,3,4,5]
selection(collection.select) { |num| num.even? }
```

I get a no defined Method error:

```
undefined method `even?' for #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:select>
```

I'm looking for a return of even numbers in the array. I can get the `select` `even?` combo work in other examples of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you are passing an enumerator object in to your "selection" method ... that is, the result of "collection.select" is an Enumerator and enumerators do not implement an "even" method.

I believe that you are trying to implement your own version of "select".  The following is one way to achieve your stated intent:  "I'm looking for a return of even numbers in the array."

```
def selection(array)

  results = []
  for item in array do
    results << item if yield item 
  end
  results
end

collection = [1,2,3,4,5]
puts selection(collection) { |num| num.even? }

# => [2,4]
```

https://mixandgo.com/learn/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes is a nice reference

Comment: Yes thank you. I realized that I had to have a conditional for this. Oh and a simple call without the 'puts' returns the selected array.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- `Array#select` returns an `Enumerator` instance if no block was given to it
- then you call `selection` method passing the result of call to `collection.select` as an argument and `{ |num| num.even? }` as block
- inside your `selection` function you `yield` the argument (an `Enumerator` instance) to the block
- in the block you call `even?` on the block argument, resulting in the error message you receive.

I am unsure what’s wrong with `collection.select(&:even?)`, but if you want to re-implement it yourself, here you go:

```
def selection(array)
  # convention: return enumerator unless block is given
  return enum_for(:selection) unless block_given?

  enumerator = array.each
  result = []

  loop do
    (value = enumerator.next) rescue return result
    result.push(value) if yield value
  end
end

selection([1,2,3,4,5]) { |num| num.even? }
#⇒ [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

yield(array) is passing the whole array in one go to the block given to the method, so it is trying to call even? on the array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'one go'.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your question what you think should be happening.

Comment: Done. Looking for a return of even numbers in the array.

Comment: @DaveNewton “You yield the array”—nope, it’s `Enumerator` instance returned by `select` what gets yielded.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Whoops, yep, missed the `.select` somehow :/